# AngularJS - disable float filtering

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm creating a directive in AngularJs.
Directive will receive from app controller a JSON object and based on that the directive will display the content.

I made a simple demo based on my problem that can be found at: http://jsfiddle.net/darkyndy/6StLm/

Now my JSON looks something like:

`ctrlItemJson = {
        myk: "something",
        state: {
            step: 1.0
        }
    };`

Why in directive-link, controller and view when I'm accessing `state.step` I get **1** instead of **1.0** ?

Setting value as string `'1.0'` it works, but for me I need to be exactly the same way how it was sent by the controller.

Later edit:
This is mainly from Javascript as if you try
`var a = 1.0` and then try `console.log(a)` you will see `1`

In this case for my issue I will discuss with API guys to send strings...

**Solution**:

**1.** In case you cannot control value:

For where you want to keep decimals (decimals are zeros, eg: `1.0`, `2.00`) instead of using floats then use Strings (eg: `'1.0'`, `'2.00'`).

**2.** In case you can control and know precision (directive will decide precision):

Then check responses for this question.
Example: http://jsfiddle.net/SE5s3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not something AngularJS related, but rather JavaScript. For example,

```
var a = 2.0;
```

is actually just 2.

You can also use the number filter in Angular if you want your numbers to specific decimal places:

```
    template: '<input type="text" value="{{dyItemJson.state.step | number:2}}"/>',
```

Comment: Yes, you are right that is mainly from JS.

Your solution may work for others, but for me it doesn't as I get that JSON from an API and I'm "blind", meaning that I don't know if value is `1.0` or `1.00` or `1` :)

Answer (score 1):

You can specify a certain float precision in JavaScript using `.toPrecision(x)`, where `x` is the precision you want.

Here's a version of your jsfiddle that implements this: http://jsfiddle.net/SE5s3/

The specific code I changed:

`<input type="text" value="{{dyItemJson.state.step.toPrecision(2)}}"/>`

Comment: For my case I cannot do this, as value is retrieved from an API and I'm "blind", meaning that I don't know if value is `1.0` or `1.00` or `1` :)

So hardcoding precision doesn't work.

Comment: In that case, you have to get the value as a string. You can always count how many decimals you need from the string later.